# Make margin below positioned element

Tags: css, css-position, margin

I know how to use margins in CSS, and they work for the pages on my site which have elements that are longer than the one in my sidebar, but when the sidebar element is the tallest thing on the page, there is no margin between the bottom of it and the bottom of the page, because the sidebar element uses absolute positioning.

Here is my code:

```
.bio {
  position:absolute;
  right:140px;
  top:205px;
  width:170px;
  font-size:11pt;
  color:#4F305A;
  background-color:#E6E6E6;
  padding:30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px groove #5C4B65;
  z-index:-1;
  line-height:23px;
}
```

So my question is: is there any way to make sure there is a certain amount of empty space (like a margin) below an absolutely-positioned element?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @emmanuel okay, there is it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any problems simply adding a margin to the sidebar element. That means the problem is somewhere else in your code.

```
#sidebar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    right: 140px;
    top: 205px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/01rt9mtp/1/